Deck.gl: Point cloud data not getting rendered
I have following program to render cesium point tiles using deck.gl:
import { load } from '@loaders.gl/core';
import {Tileset3D} from '@loaders.gl/tiles';
import { CesiumIonLoader } from '@loaders.gl/3d-tiles';
import { WebMercatorViewport } from '@deck.gl/core';
import { Deck } from '@deck.gl/core';
import { TileLayer } from '@deck.gl/geo-layers';



const tilesetUrl = 'http://localhost/mytileset/tileset.json';
const options = { ion: { loadGLTF: true } };
const tilesetJson = await load(tilesetUrl, CesiumIonLoader, {...options});

// Setup the viewport using Web Mercator
const latitude = 18.5204;
const longitude = 73.8567;
const zoom = 14;
const viewport = new WebMercatorViewport({ latitude, longitude, zoom });

const tileset3d = new Tileset3D(tilesetJson, {
  throttleRequests: false,
  onTileLoad: (tile) => console.log(tile)
});

tileset3d.selectTiles(viewport);

// visible tiles
const visibleTiles = tileset3d.tiles.filter((tile) => tile.selected);

while (!tileset3d.isLoaded()) {
  await tileset3d.selectTiles(viewport);
}

// Create a Deck.gl TileLayer to display the tileset
const tileLayer = new TileLayer({
  id: 'tile-layer',
  data: tilesetJson,
  onTileLoad: (tile) => console.log('Tile loaded: ', tile),
  onTileUnload: (tile) => console.log('Tile unloaded: ', tile),
  minZoom: 0,
  maxZoom: 19,
  renderSubLayers: (props) => {
    const { deck, tile, viewport } = props;
    return []; // Render sublayers here if needed
  }
});

// Create the Deck.gl instance and render the map
const deckgl = new Deck({
  container: 'app',  // The ID of the HTML container to render the map
  layers: [tileLayer],
  initialViewState: viewport,
  controller: true,
});

On chrome console I see no error and tile loading related messages displayed. But no point data is rendered on page.
What am I missing in this code?
PS: My index.html is
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DeckGL + Cesium Ion Tiles Viewer</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #app {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- This is the container where Deck.gl will render the map -->
    <div id="app"></div>

    <!-- Include your main JavaScript file -->
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

